# SQL query, how to do the sum() on some field, but fall back to 'NA' if one of them the values in sum() is null

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate-functions

We use mysql. At certain place in the SQL query, I have to calculate a field as sum of other values but at the same time, to take into account that if one of these values that are being summed up has a value null, the calculated value is not the sum() but null as well.

(for the sake of simplicity of the question I say that the fallback condition value is null, but in any case, some fix value).

How to integrate additional fallback conditions into sum() function in mysql? Example of data is:

```
id  value  some_fk
1   1      AL
2   3      AL
3   jak    AL
4   7      AL
5   6      AL
```

if I sum them up, like this:

```
select sum(value) from tmp;
```

, I want to be returned value 'not summable', since there is a value 'jak' in one of the rows, which is not summable with the others.

Comment: You can't. `SUM()` is numeric, `'NA'` is string.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `IFNULL()`?

*Sample data*

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE(ID INT, SAL INT);
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(1,1000);
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(1,2000);
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(2,'3000');
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(2,'1000');
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(3,NULL);
---------NEW SAMPLE BASED ON COMMENT---------
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(3,NULL);
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(3,'MYTEXT');
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(3,500);
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(4,'MYTEXT2');
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(4,'MYTEXT3');
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(4,10.2);
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(5,NULL);
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(5,NULL);
```

If I understood correctly, for the above data you are expecting the result as shown below.

```
+----+------------+
| ID | SUM_RESULT |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 3000       |
+----+------------+
| 2  | 4000       |
+----+------------+
| 3  | N/A        |
+----+------------+
```

In that case, you can use

```
SELECT ID,
       IFNULL(SUM(SAL),'N/A') AS SUM_RESULT 
FROM SAMPLE GROUP BY ID
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f6d0b03c313c7296044c04d72cf2bc9c)

*UPDATE BASED ON COMMENT:*

You can use the below query if you want to display your error message if a group contains some text.

```
select ID,
       CASE WHEN 
            MAX(CASE WHEN SAL REGEXP ('^[0-9]+$') THEN SAL ELSE 'N/A' END) !='N/A' 
            THEN
                SUM(SAL)
       ELSE 'NOT SUMMABLE' END AS MYRESULT
FROM SAMPLE
GROUP BY ID
```

*OUTPUT*

```
+----+--------------+
| ID |   MYRESULT   |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | 3000         |
|  2 | 4200         |
|  3 | NOT SUMMABLE |
|  4 | NOT SUMMABLE |
|  5 | NOT SUMMABLE |
+----+--------------+
```

[CHECK DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=99776707bafd9ed3025e3971dcd8fd62)

Comment: Your example it pretty basic, I need another row there with id 3, with some numbers in the value column....

Comment: Alright ! Would you mind adding a sample data and expected output to your post so that we can get more clarity? @VladimirDespotovic

Comment: I think you are right. my example was not full enough. The sum() should fall onto the default value (null or anything else I specify), also on some other fixed values, not only null. Any time it is a text actually. Does it exist something like iftext(this, then, else)?

Comment: Please see my updated questions with some more specifics.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy SUM() will return null only if all the summed values are null. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d43fa18277602282f7b2045696435ede

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your comment @VladimirDespotovic

Comment: Yes, you are right @forpas. My understanding was that the OP wants to display some text when consolidated `SUM()` is `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this `CASE` expression:

```
select 
  case 
    when exists (
      select 1 from tmp
      where value is null or concat(value + 0) <> value
    ) then null
    else (select sum(value) from tmp)  
  end result
```

`EXISTS` checks for invalid integer values and nulls and returns `null` if it finds any.
The `ELSE` part safely returns the sum.
See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2aRRJML1HBwnyTEJHbwMTJ/0).